# Mock parent final method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I want to mock a subclass method which is inherited.This method cannot be overriden since it's final.When using "when ,thenReturn " mockito is calling the real method which causes some exceptions and I want to avoid that.

```
class A{
    final String doSomething()
    {
        //Some treatement 
        return "";
    }
}
class B extends A{
    //
}

class TestB {
    @Test
    public void test(){}
    B b=mock(B.class);
    when(B.doSomething()).thenReturn("");// it fails because it calls //the real method of A
}
```

}

Comment: Uhm...so you want to test a final method, which cannot actually be declared in class B, but call it on class B? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: Yes , but since we can call doSomething() from an instance of B , I want to mock this method.

Comment: Calling it on B just delegates to call it on A. I would not know how to change that. You could only create a new method in B, which calls it on A, but catches the exception. Not sure if that would count as an answer, though.

Comment: Yes it may works , but I wanted to know if there is any tricks that let me mock the parent class  when mocking its subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons why could be asking this questions:

a) you are dealing with some kind of 3rd party library/design that you can't change; but that you somehow want to test. In that case using PowerMock can be an option, as PowerMock manipulates byte code and makes it possible to mock final methods/classes. But: PowerMock is famous for creating all kinds of weird problems; and seriously: you are much better of not using it.

b) you are getting "unit testing" wrong: you **never** create a mock object of class B in order to test something on class B. You only mock objects X, Y, Z that your code in B needs to do something.

So, your real problem is: you have some method "doSomethingElse()" on B that you want to test. And "doSomethingElse()" calls "doSomething()" ... and your test fails because you can't control the behavior of "doSomething()". There are two options to get out of that problem:

1) Do you really need inheritance? Must B really extend A, or would it be better if a B object ... simply owned an A object? (if so, you can mock that A object and gain control over its methods). Ever heard about [CoI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)?

2) You reverse dependencies; like in:

```
abstract class A { 
  final void doSomething() { doSomethingSpecific() ... }
  abstract void doSomethingSpecific();
}

class B extends A { @Override void doSomethingSpecific() { ...
```

resulting in a "proper OO" solution to your "testing" problem.

Besides: if "doSomething()" is final on class A, then that should be in order to achieve [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle): you define some behavior on A that subclasses can use (or use indirectly) and that **should** not change. So, you can turn back to your design, and maybe that final was added "for the wrong reason", then it might be fine to simply remove the keyword.